# Perl - cannot send image via API - Throws error can't open file name No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 419

Tags: perl, api

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use File::Slurp;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $baseUrl     = 'xxxxx';
my $accessToken = 'xxxxx';

my $shelfGuid = 'xxxxx';
my $url         = $baseUrl . 'yyyy';
my $sourceFile  = '/home/example.png';
my $destFile    = 'example.png';
my $ua          = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->default_header( 'authorization' => "bearer $accessToken" );
my $response    = $ua->post($url,
   'Content_Type' => 'form-data',
   Content => [
      file => [
         name => $sourceFile,
         filename => $destFile,
         Content_Type => 'image/png'
      ],
      model => { ShelfGuid => $shelfGuid }
   ]
);

print $response;
```

Getting this error - Can't open file name: No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 419.

Tried a whole day without any progress. Help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to open a file named `name`. Replace

```
file => [ name => $sourceFile, filename => $destFile, Content_Type => 'image/png' ]
```

with

```
file => [ $sourceFile, $destFile, Content_Type => 'image/png' ]
```

---

Unrelated, the value of the other field looks wrong too.

```
model => { ShelfGuid => $shelfGuid }
```

The value should be a string, or an array ref for a file upload, but not a hash ref.

Comment: Thanks ikegami. This solved the problem posted. But still a general question. Is it the right way to upload an image to the api using perl ?

Comment: Well, it's the way to go to use LWP to make an HTTP POST request that contains a form with an upload field.